# How to Draw Images Dynamically on Android?

Tags: android, surfaceview

is it a good way to draw image(just some lines), that refresh dynamically, has transparent background and is located between other views? For now I am using surface view, but for transparent background it's need setZOrderOnTop(true) and it looks ugly

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032214/best-way-to-draw-an-image-dynamically

Comment: Use a custom View. http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also try drawing lines using Views. For example:

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/sep"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/LightGrey" />
```

Create lines for every possibility. Keep all lines invisible. Make selected line visible according to your program logic. This does away with managing SurfaceView.

Comment: ok, how to rotate it to random angle and point to x1 y1, x2 y2

Comment: I was imagining that you have something like two columns of text/buttons on either side of screen and are trying to show connectors between the two. A view can always be rotated by overriding onDraw. You need to tell in better detail what you are trying to do so that SO can help you better.